# Flatten the dataframe column using expload

Tags: python, pandas, explode

I have one data frame having column name `eperson_id` as below

```
    eperson_id
    None
    []
    NaN
    [61792146704412477760]
    [8429158820359919752,87317204426914512343]
    [94049068360051725854,75755131247948382378,94049068360051725854]
    [94049068360051725854,39181670842227113377,39181670842227113377,75755131247948382378]
    enter code here
```

I want to explode each value and remove the duplicate, blank, none, and NaN and remove square bracket as well in rows

final output should be as below

```
    eperson_id
    61792146704412477760
    8429158820359919752
    87317204426914512343
    94049068360051725854,
    39181670842227113377
    75755131247948382378
```

I tried but failed to output as expected

```
df.assign(eperson_id=df['eperson_id'].str.split(',')).explode('eperson_id')
df.explode('eperson_id')
```

Comment: What is `print (df['eperson_id'].head().tolist())` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#if values are strings first convert to lists with remove []
df = df.assign(eperson_id=df['eperson_id'].str.strip('[]').str.split(','))
```

And then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `ignore_index` parameter for default index (New parameter in version 1.0.0.):

```
df = (df.explode('eperson_id')
        .dropna(subset=['eperson_id'])
        .drop_duplicates('eperson_id', ignore_index=True))
print (df)
             eperson_id
0  61792146704412477760
1   8429158820359919752
2  87317204426914512343
3  94049068360051725854
4  75755131247948382378
5  39181670842227113377
```

Answer (score 1):

If the output of `type(df.loc[4,'eperson_id'])` is `string/Object`  then use(If It's `list` then ignore the code written in 1st code block):

```
#1st code block

df['eperson_id']=df['eperson_id'].replace('nan',None,regex=True)

df['eperson_id']=df['eperson_id'].apply(pd.eval)
```

then use [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method **,** [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method **,** [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method and [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method:

```
df=df.explode('eperson_id').drop_duplicates(subset=['eperson_id']).dropna(subset=['eperson_id']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now If you print `df['eperson_id']` you will get your desired output:

```
    eperson_id
0   61792146704412477760
1   8429158820359919752
2   87317204426914512343
3   94049068360051725854
4   75755131247948382378
5   39181670842227113377
```